# How can I use wxLua in LuaLaTeX on Windows?

Tags: miktex, luatex, windows, lua

I have some problems using wxLua in LuaLateX.

This works:

```
lua simpleui.lua
```

(print instead of `tex.print`)

But if I try this:

```
lualatex wx.tex
```

it doesn't work.

```
\documentclass{article}
\directlua{require("simpleui.lua")}
\usepackage{color}

\begin{document}
  {\Huge\color{\ChoicewxRadioBox} Test!}
\end{document}
```

Error:

[image]

`simpleui.lua`:

```
require("wx")

frame = nil

function HandleEvents(event)
  local name = event:GetEventObject():DynamicCast("wxWindow"):GetName()
  print(string.format("\\global\\def\\Choice%s{%s}", name, event:GetString()))
end

function main()
  frame = wx.wxFrame(wx.NULL,
                     wx.wxID_ANY,
                     "Erstellen Sie Ihr PDF-Dokument mit LuaTeX",
                     wx.wxDefaultPosition,
                     wx.wxSize(185, 85),
                     wx.wxDEFAULT_FRAME_STYLE)
  local panel = wx.wxPanel(frame, wx.wxID_ANY)
  local choices = {"blue", "red", "green"}
  local radioBox = wx.wxRadioBox(panel,
                                 wx.wxID_ANY,
                                 "Farbe",
                                 wx.wxDefaultPosition,
                                 wx.wxDefaultSize,
                                 choices, 1,wx.wxRA_SPECIFY_ROWS)
  frame:Connect(wx.wxID_ANY,
                wx.wxEVT_COMMAND_RADIOBOX_SELECTED,
                HandleEvents)
  frame:Show(true)
end

main()

wx.wxGetApp():MainLoop()
```

The folder contains the following files:

- `lua51.dll`
- `lua5.1.dll`
- `simpleui.lua`
- `wx.tex`
- `wx.dll`

I am using Lua 5.1 and LuaTeX beta-0.70.2 (MikTeX 2.9).

`texlua simpleui.lua` doesn't work:

[image]

The example is on page 24:

http://www.dante.de/events/Archiv/dante2012/Programm/Vortraege/vortrag-meigen.pdf

Edit: I was able to compile the wxlua libs on Linux and it works, but i still haven't any solution for windows.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! The information you've provided so far is a bit sparse. What does the file `simpleui.lua` contain, and where is it located? Is `wxLua` a precompiled library? Which versions of Lua and luatex do you use?

Comment: I can't get wxLua to compile, so just few thoughts. What is the output when you try to run `texlua simpleui.lua`? This will use same interpreter as `lualatex` as opposed to `lua`, which may be different version of interpreter. Also, what about running the gui with lua, generate the document on the fly and call `lalatex` from here? I have a feeling that it would be easier to maintain.

Comment: I can't get wxLua to compile on linux too. ^^ I am going to try the command and add the result to my question. There is no need to run the gui in pure lua, i just want to try, what is possible directly in lualatex.

Comment: I have a MacBook and thus can't replicate your Windows-based setup. It looks to me like lua and luatex aren't looking for compiled libraries in the same places.

Comment: I've tried VCLua on Windows and got the same error. I can't find the VCLua library or the source for Linux -.-

Comment: Perhaps [this](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/812486/de) (in english [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/812486/en)) can be related?

Comment: I've already tried Microsoft's solution but it didn't help.

Comment: Don't provide information as image which can be text.

Answer (score 0):

The german message says `%1 is not a valid Win32 application`.

May be you first quickly check all your wx module files (may be `wc*.*' ?), if they look like the ususal DLL files.

It is quite possible that you have different environment settings (especially `PATH`) when running `lua` directly and when `lua` is executed inside the luatex.

Then different versions may be found of 1. what was already loaded in the moment (DLL files and the lua itself), 2. what is going to be loaded.

Take control of that.

Longer answer starts by suggestion to find of what various version of DLL files you have (including the lua.exe itself versus the built lua in luatex.)

Then you should compare the environment variables on your command line and those that are available to DLL started by luatex. May simply execute the command prompt (interactivelly or not) from inside luatex. Create `AAA.BAT`
containing

```
echo I AM HERE
SET
echo I-would  lua someprog.lua
ehoo I-would  lua simpleui.lua
```

and make it executed from inside of your TeX file.
Check you see `I AM HERE`, meditate about what `SET` outputs and then start testing what happens if you remove `echo I-would` -- for some simple someprog.lua first.

Also the two files `lua51.dll`, `lua5.1.dll` might be part of the problem. Loading DLL's in the current directory can be sometimes done and sometimes not.